# What will be the sudo password in windows new Ubuntu terminal

Tags: windows-10, terminal

Windows has launched its new terminal which is also having Ubuntu terminal. Ubuntu terminal is asking password to install things with the help of sudo. I tried the windows PIN and the Microsoft accounts password but none worked, so what could be the default password for this new terminal?

Comment: There isn't a default password[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1360091/set-wsl-sudo-password-to-my-windows-password)  It's looking for the WSL user's password you configured when you installed WSL Ubuntu[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1220436/windows-subsystem-for-linux-sudo-does-not-ask-for-password-everytime)

Comment: No, this terminal app is available in windows store, I installed it and opened it, no user was created.

Comment: [How to reset kali linux password in windows subsystem for linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1330054/how-to-reset-kali-linux-password-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux/1369917#1369917)

Comment: By "Ubuntu terminal" I assume you are talking about the Ubuntu Windows Subsystem for Linux instance, are you not?  **I am aware of the new terminal program on the Windows Store.**

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right

Comment: Check the linked questions.  **Especially, the one on how to reset the linux password, it isn't limited to just Kali.**